# Why postMessage fails on FileSystemFileHandle?

Tags: javascript, webapi

I have `index.html`:

```js
const openButton = document.querySelector('#open'),
  pickerOpts = {
    types: [{
      accept: {
        "text/*": [".txt"],
      },
    }, ],
    excludeAcceptAllOption: true,
    multiple: false,
  }

openButton.addEventListener('click', async() => {
  const handle = await window.showOpenFilePicker(pickerOpts),
    obj = {
      a: 'a'
    },
    tab = window.open('tab.html')
  setTimeout(() => {
    // not work, the tab.html receives nothing
    tab.postMessage(handle, '*')
    // works fine
    // tab.postMessage(obj, '*')
  }, 1000)
})
```

```html
<button id="open">open</button>
```

and `tab.html`:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  console.log(e.data)
})
```

The `postMessage` works fine for general JavaScript objects but fails to send a `FileSystemFileHandle`. How should I fix this?

[The structured clone algorithm - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types) indicates that `FileSystemFileHandle` should be supported.

Comment: Although the documentation says that the message argument is serialized using structured clone, I wouldn't be surprised if some implementations are restricting it to transferable objects.

Comment: How do you load your page? From a web-server (be it localhost), or from the file:// protocol? FileSystemFileHandle are indeed serializable, but trying to do so with a cross-origin document will throw a DataCloneError. And from the file:// protocol your 2 pages would be cross-origin.

Comment: @Kaiido From the file:// protocol. I didn't see a `DataCloneError` or any other error in Edge/Chrome. Is this a silent error or I can modify some settings to see the error?  I am trying to make a small tool to edit local files without the users having a server-running environment. Any other API that helps this? (Though with a server everything would get simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileSystemFileHandle` objects can indeed be cloned through the structured cloning algorithm used by `postMessage()`, however, if your two documents are not on the same origin, this operation should throw a `DataCloneError` exception on the receiving end when it will try to deserialize the object.

Note that two documents on the `file://` system will be seen as cross-origin.

To handle such an error, you should be able to add a `messageerror` event on the receiving end, however this is the case only in Firefox (when using  `navigator.storage.getDirectory()`), but not in Chrome.
In that browser, there is thus nothing that tells us that it failed, apart from the fact that `data` will be `null`. But this is against the specs, so may be considered a bug.

But anyway, you can know that it will throw if you can't access the window you're posting to, so that would help you only a little.
Instead, what you will probably have to do is to set up a proxy API where your main page will request the FileSystem, and then let the popup navigate it through calls to `postMessage`. My advice would be to set up a unique `MessageChannel` to this effect, so that you can promisify the communication.

However rewriting the whole API is not a small project, so you may to instead start only with the few methods you're sure you'll be using.